# object reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Hi I have use the following code snippet

```
   var date = new Date(),
       modifiedDate = date;

   modifiedDate.setDate(modifiedDate.getDate() + 1);
```

In javascript while modifying the modifiedDate object affect the date . Is there any other way to skip modification in date while modifying modifiedDate

Comment: object are passed by reference in javascript, hence @dystroy gave a correct solutiong

Comment: Raja, you asked 36 question and you accepted 0 answer. Please have a look at this : [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 5):

Yes : clone the `Date` object so that you have two distinct objects :

```
var date = new Date(),
    modifiedDate = new Date(date.getTime());
```